# what is the time complexity of blow functions?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Which function has a lower time complexity? why?
I want to compare two lists in python but I don't know which function is faster than the other functions.

```
def compare_with_set(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1) & set(list2))


def compare_with_zip(list1, list2):
    return [i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i == j]


def compare_with_for(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for item in list1:
        if item in list2:
            list3.append(item)
    return list3


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

compare_with_set(a, b)
compare_with_zip(a, b)
compare_with_for(a, b)
```

Comment: What results did you get from your performance testing?

Comment: you can test the performance with the built-in ``timeit`` module.

Comment: Also, all 3 functions do different things so theres no point in comparing them

Comment: @Sayse 
are you know time complexity? please tell me per function.

Comment: @MikeScotty
thanks for the guide. but my question is the time complexity of my functions. are you know time complexity? please tell me per function.

Comment: @rmaleki the time complexity of compare_with_set and  compare_with_zip is O(n) in average, the compare_with_for is O(n^2). BUT, compare_with_zip result is not like the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

In the real world, it depends on the data you're working with. There can be negligible difference between methods in small scales and considerable difference between them in large scales.

### Big-O Notation

That being said, if you're looking for something like the theoretical [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), then we'd have to look at how `list()` and `set()` and `zip()` are implemented. A very basic rule of thumb is to consider each loop in range of `n` to be of order `n` and then add, multiply, etc.
For example, the function `compare_with_for()` is of O(n^2) because it iterate over list1 (n) and for each element iterates over list2 (n) so n*n=O(n^2).

*Edit: Other big-O approximations are answered by users in the comments. Users such as [Dor Meiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7902605/dor-meiri), who deserve the credit for their efforts. I am not going to rewrite their answer as mine, all the credit is theirs.*

### Execution Timing in Python

And in order to time the execution of your code, you can simply do it either with `timeit` or `time.perf_counter` *as suggested by user [Dor Meiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7902605/dor-meiri)*.

Here's how you can do it with the latter:

```py
import time

def compare_with_set(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1) & set(list2))


def compare_with_zip(list1, list2):
    return [i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i == j]


def compare_with_for(list1, list2):
    list3 = []
    for item in list1:
        if item in list2:
            list3.append(item)
    return list3


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

start = time.perf_counter()
compare_with_set(a, b)
end = = time.perf_counter()
duration_compare_with_set = end - start

start = time.perf_counter()
compare_with_zip(a, b)
end = = time.perf_counter()
duration_compare_with_zip = end - start

start = time.perf_counter()
compare_with_for(a, b)
end = = time.perf_counter()
duration_compare_with_for = end - start
```

Edit 1:
Change `time.time()` to `time.perf_counter()` as suggested by [Dor Meiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7902605/dor-meiri).

Edit 2:
Improved formatting.

Comment: It is better to use time.perf_counter() instead of time.time() for measuring duration

Comment: thanks for an answer. are you know time complexity compare_with_zip and compare_with_set?

Comment: @rmaleki compare_with_set is O(n) in average and O(n^2) in worst case (set creation is O(n), set iteration is O(n), set search is O(1) in the average case and O(n) in worst case) compare_with_zip is O(n) in worst case (because iteration is O(n), appending and comparing is O(1))

Comment: @DorMeiri Thanks for the tip! I learned something new!

Comment: @M.H.Tajaddini very very tanks.

Answer (score 1):

compare_with_set is O(n) in average and O(n^2) in worst case because set creation is O(n), set iteration is O(n), set search is O(1) in the average case and O(n) in worst case
compare_with_zip is O(n) because iteration is O(n), appending and comparing is O(1)
compare_with_for is O(n^2) because iteration and search is O(n)

Remark: compare_with_zip does not have the same result as the others